# Apple HealthKit HKHealthStore.requestAuthorization() return error

Tags: swift, healthkit

I am trying to access some of the HealthKit data, but am getting "Invalid type identifier array" error. I have defined the Health Records Usage Description, Health Share Usage Description and Health Update Usage Description in the Info.plist. Here is the code snippet:

```
if HKHealthStore.isHealthDataAvailable() {
    guard let allergiesType = HKObjectType.clinicalType(forIdentifier: .allergyRecord),
          let medicationsType = HKObjectType.clinicalType(forIdentifier: .medicationRecord) else {
        fatalError("*** Unable to create the requested types ***")
    }
    
    healthStore.getRequestStatusForAuthorization(toShare: [], read: [allergiesType, medicationsType]) { (status, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("AppDelegate::getRequestStatusForAuthorization(): error=\(String(describing: error))")
            return
        }
        
        switch status {
        case .unnecessary:
            print("Application has already sent request for Authorization")
        default:
            print("Unknown status for Authorization")
            healthStore.requestAuthorization(toShare: [], read: [allergiesType, medicationsType]) { (success, error) in
                if let error = error {
                    print("AppDelegate::requestAuthorization(): error=\(String(describing: error))")
                    return
                }
                guard success else {
                    print("AppDelegate::requestAuthorization(): success=\(String(describing: error))")
                    return
                }
            }   // healthStore.requestAuthorization()
        }   // switch status
    }   // healthStore.getRequestStatusForAuthorization()
} else {    // HKHealthStore.isHealthDataAvailable()
    // No HealthKit on this platform
    print("AppDelegate::isHealthDataAvailable() - No HealthKit on this platform")
}
```

After the prompt for authorization for the 2 items, I see:

```
Unknown status for Authorization <= This message is seen before the authorization screen is shown
2022-05-23 15:27:41.988596-0700 myHealth[53345:4120994] [auth] FAILED prompting authorization request to share (
), read (
    HKClinicalTypeIdentifierAllergyRecord,
    HKClinicalTypeIdentifierMedicationRecord
)
AppDelegate::requestAuthorization(): error=Error Domain=com.apple.healthkit Code=3 "Invalid type identifier array (expected NSArray, found __NSDictionaryM)" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Invalid type identifier array (expected NSArray, found __NSDictionaryM)}
```

Why am I seeing the "Invalid type identifier array" error?

Answer (score 0):

[`getRequestStatusForAuthorization()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkhealthstore/2994346-getrequeststatusforauthorization) takes a `Set`, you're passing an array. I wonder why the compiler does let you do that in the first place, and then I wonder why you get that weird message. Have you tried converting that array to a Set yourself first?

Comment: It does not matter whether I use array or Set for the healthStore.getRequestStatusForAuthorization() and healthStore.requestAuthorization() calls - the error they emit is exactly the same in both cases